# where is the my.cnf file for mysql server located on windows?

Tags: windows-7, mysql, mysql5

I'm running MySQL Server 5.6 on Windows 7 and would like to enable slow query logging. Unfortunately, it is not immediately obvious to me where the my.cnf file is.

I see `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my-default.ini` but according to that...

```
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.
```

I don't see any my.cnf or my.ini file in `C:\Users\neubert\AppData\Roaming\MySQL` either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the location with MySQL Server 5.7:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

If an ini file exists it will be in

```
c:\Windows
```

It's typically named

```
my.ini
```